# Fix for CWE-113: Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences in HTTP Headers ('HTTP Response Splitting')

Tags: c#

After running veracode scan, I got the CWE 113 error. I had found a solution to replace the cookie value, but still the issue is not fixed.

> Fix for CWE-113: Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences in HTTP
>   Headers ('HTTP Response Splitting')

```
string ReplaceHTTPRequestValue(string Value)
{
    string replacedValue = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
    {
        replacedValue = Value.Replace("\r", string.Empty)
                                .Replace("%0d", string.Empty)
                                .Replace("%0D", string.Empty)
                                .Replace("\n", string.Empty)
                                .Replace("%0a", string.Empty)
                                .Replace("%0A", string.Empty);
    }
    return replacedValue;
}

void WebTrends_PreRender()
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["WT_CID"];
    string campaignIdVal = string.Empty;
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        campaignIdVal = ReplaceHTTPRequestValue(Request.Cookies["WT_CID"].Value);
    }
    else
    {
        campaignIdVal = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: string ReplaceHTTPRequestValue is function, i could'nt format this properly, please execuse and suggest me solutions. Thanks Vignesh

Comment: Have you found any solution to fix the flaw Vignesh?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this link
https://community.veracode.com/s/question/0D53n00007YVaMrCAL/how-to-fix-flaws-for-cwe-id-113-http-response-splitting

> It is likely the reason the flaw continues to be reported is because
> the functions you are using are not in the list of Supported Cleansing
> Functions, which you can find in the Help Center here:
> https://help.veracode.com/go/review_cleansers. For example the
> supported function org.owasp.encoder.Encode.forJava() would cleanse
> for CWE-113, as well as CWE-117, CWE-80 and CWE-93. Please note that
> it is important to select the appropriate cleansing function for the
> context.

Answer (score 0):

string ReplaceHTTPRequestValue(string Value)
{
string NonCRLF = string.Empty;

```
        foreach (char item in Value)
        {

            NonCRLF += item.ToString().Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r","");
        }
        return NonCRLF;
    }
```